# How can I retry calling an AWL CLI function in Bash until it succeeds?

Tags: bash, aws-cli

I have a Bash script that gets executed inside Codebuild--it currently reads the last line in a file and, depending on what's in it, kicks off some AWS cli commands to deploy a new Lambda. I'm trying to update the script to read multiple lines and be able to deploy multiple Lambdas, but my current attempt at just putting the original code in a loop for each line in the file failed with the error `An error occurred (ResourceConflictException) when calling the UpdateFunctionCode operation: The operation cannot be performed at this time. An update is in progress for resource blahblahblah.`

I think putting the CLI command inside a loop and sleeping until the command executes successfully should work. However, I'm pretty inexperienced with Bash and not quite sure of the syntax to do it, and it's not the easiest thing to test locally. Something like:

```
mins=0
while [aws lambda update-function-code blahblahblah -ne 0] && [ $mins -lt 5 ]
do
    echo "Resource conflict...sleeping for 1 min"
    sleep 1m
    mins=$(( $mins + 1 ))
done
```

There are actual args instead of blahblahblah, and I'm not sure how long I actually want to wait for the resource conflict to resolve. Also, earlier in the script, `set -eou pipefail` has been called, so I don't know if I'd need to unset it or do something special to capture the output of the AWS command.

I'd most like to know how to actually write the code using this logic, but if there are any problems with doing it this way that I should account for, or entirely different and better ways of doing it, that would be helpful, too.

Comment: You have syntax issues, validate your code using https://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: implement exponential backoff in your code: https://coderwall.com/p/--eiqg/exponential-backoff-in-bash